# PHP regex - find and replace link

Tags: php, regex, replace, html-parsing

I am trying to do this regex match and replace but not able to do it.

Example

```
<a href=one target=home>One</a>
<a href=two>Two</a>
<a href=three target=head>Three</a>
<a href=four>Four</a>
<a href=five target=foot>Five</a>
```

I want to find each set of the a tags and replace with something like this

Find

```
<a href=one target=home>One</a>
```

Change to

```
<a href='one'>One</a>
```

same way the the rest of the a tags.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: I'm new with regex, I don't know how to find the match to add the quotes to href.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
preg_replace('/<a(.*)href=(")?([a-zA-Z]+)"? ?(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/', '<a href='$3'>$5</a>', '{{your data}}');
```

Comment: Works! Thank you mightyuhu!

Answer (score 5):

Using [`DomDocument()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) would be an easier way to work with HTML.

```
<?php
    $str = '<a href=one target=home>One</a>
<a href=two>Two</a>
<a href=three target=head>Three</a>
<a href=four>Four</a>
<a href=five target=foot>Five</a>';
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($str);
    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($anchors as $a)
    {
        if ($a->hasAttribute('target'))
        {
            $a->removeAttribute('target');
        }
    }
    $str = $dom->saveHTML();
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hcnZMY)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not add the quotes to href.

Comment: Are you sure? I see quotes in my in my fiddle. But feel free to add `
    $dom->formatOutput = true;` just beforfe the last line and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a regex, try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/<a [^>]*href=([^\'" ]+) ?[^>]*>/',"<a href='\1'>",$str);
```

I don't recommend using a regular expression to do this though.